# how to print the entire linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

I am working on creating a linked list program in C. I am having trouble displaying the entire list. All I can get to display is the first and last elements. Not sure what is going on. I have tried changing the links to every different way I can think of, and none of them will quite work. I am pretty sure this is just a simple mistake I am making somewhere. I would appreciate any help and suggestions.

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
     int data;
     struct node *next;
}
*start = NULL;

void display();
void create ();

int main(void)
{
int numberOfElements = 0;
printf("How many elements do you want to enter?\n");
scanf("%d",&numberOfElements);

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; ++i){
     printf("Please enter data for element number %d\n", i+1);
     createList();
}

display();


     return 0;
}

void display(){
     struct node *tempNode;

     printf("Now displaying the list\n");
     tempNode = start;
     while (tempNode != NULL){
          printf("%d---> ",tempNode->data);
          tempNode = tempNode->next;
     }
     printf("NULL\n");

}
void createList(){
     struct node *newNode, *current;
     newNode = (struct node *)malloc(1 * sizeof (struct node));

     //printf("Please enter the data for each element\n");
     scanf("%d", &newNode ->data);

     // For testing
     printf("You entered %d\n",newNode->data);

     newNode->next = NULL;

     if(start == NULL){
          start = newNode;
          current = newNode;
     }
     else {
          current->next = newNode;
          current = newNode;
     }
}
```

So when the user enters some data, say two elements, of 22 and 28, the display should be 22--->28--->NULL instead what is displayed is 22--->NULL

Thank you

Comment: What `current` pointer is referring to? Note that `current` is a local pointer of `createList()` and its scope is limited to the function block. Your code is accessing uninitialised `current` pointer in `createList()` for all elements except first element. Moreover, the elements never gets added to list except the first element case  where the `start` is `NULL`.  That's the reason that when you are displaying the list only first element is displayed.

Comment: `malloc` returns `void *`, you should not cast it to `node*`.  The `else` block in `createList()` is referencing the uninitialized `current`, and why would you want to set `current` and `current->next` equal to `newNode`?

Comment: There's a lot of answered questions regarding linked list creation.  Perhaps you should search for those and study the answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code expects/requires that the variable `current` in `createList` maintain its value between calls of the function. By default it doesn't work that way in C. The value of variables inside a function doesn't keep their value from call to call.

If you want a variable in a function to behave that way, you need to use the keyword `static`.

So if you change:

```
 struct node *newNode, *current;
```

to

```
     struct node *newNode;
     static struct node *current;
```

the variable `current` will keep its value between calls and your code will (probably) work.

In more technical terms you should read about "automatic storage duration" and "static storage duration".

That said, it's not a good idea to do something like that - in fact, it's a rather bad idea. Also it's a bad idea to have `start` as a global variable.

Instead you should define two variables in `main`- for instance `head` and `tail` - and pass these (or their address) to the insert-function.

Something like:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct node* head = NULL;
    struct node* tail = NULL;

    createList(&head, &tail);
    createList(&head, &tail);
    createList(&head, &tail);

    display(head);
    return 0;
}

void createList(struct node* pHead, struct node* pTail)
{
    // malloc and initialize new node

    if (*pHead == NULL)
    {
        *pHead = newNode;
        *pTail = newNode;
        return;
    }

    (*pTail)->next = newNode;
    *pTail = newNode;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I have taken some java classes but am fairly new to C, however I am eager to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, `current` is locally scoped in your `CreateList` function, though you're persisting the current node in the `current`, when  `CreateList` exits, `current` is vanished, during another call of the `CreateList`, `current` knows nothing from previous execution, as it's created as brand-new variable for this particular invocation of the function. But you're persisting the value only for first node as `start` is globally scoped, it exists unless your program finishes execution.
So, make `current` global variable, that fixes the bug:

Look at this: https://ideone.com/yWQLDL